# configure multiple log4j.xml on a single WebSphere Application Server 8.5 Base instance

Tags: log4j, websphere

I am using WebSphere Application Server 8.5 Base. I have to deploy two different EAR files on the same WebSphere instance. Two applications are required to use different log4j-properties.xml files. For a single application the steps are: Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers > server_name under Server Infrastructure > Java and Process Management > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine > Custom properties I can create a variable for the log4j-properties.xml file.  But for multiple applications on the same instance how do I configure the log4j-properties.xml ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can't you deploy the properties file in the application itself? So even if the name of the file is the same for both EARs, the files themselves are different.

Comment: I tried doing that but it did not work. None of the log files are being created.

Comment: Probably need more detail on that attempt, then. That kind of approach should work.

Comment: @dbreaux The application is set up to have multiple jar files within an ear file. I am placing the log4j.xml in conf folder of one of the jar file that has the main class. After I start the ear file from the admin console I don't see any logs what so ever.
-Sample.ear
 |-App.jar
 |-App1.jar(log4j.xml is placed here in a conf folder)
 |-App2.jar

Comment: You probably need to show the exact structure. Edit the question, please. How do you load the log4j configuration in your application? Defaults look in the classpath, where the conf directory in a jar likely wouldn't be in the classpath. But also, are your log4j log entries by any chance going to the WebSphere log instead of the file you expect? That can happen for a different reason.

Comment: @dbreaux I am unable to post any images to show the exact structure but my ear file has 6 jar files inside. I am trying to have application specific logging. I have the log4j.xml on the classpath. This is a thick client trying to connect to the server from a batch file. The local logging is happening fine. Bu this logs are being generated on the server. No the log4j log entries are not going to WebSphere log. I am trying to achieve something that is here : https://thequirksofit.blogspot.com/2015/01/external-log4j-configuration-in.html?showComment=1554147101668#c4287024710434748999

Comment: I'm trying to send you down a different path from what that article is doing. That article is sharing a single configuration file, which will, of course, write to the same log file(s). My suggestion is for each app to use a separate configuration file, each in its own war. This does work, so if it's not working for you, we'll probably need to see the exact name and location of the config files and the exact way you have log4j loading them.

Comment: @dbreaux Yes My intention is to use seperate configuration file, each in its own EAR. In EAR file I have 6 jar files. One of the jar files has the main class. In that jar file in the conf folder I placed my log4j.xml file. This all works good if I am executing from eclipse(I am able to see the log files generated on my local laptop). I use a batch file to connect to the server. I am able to access the application and the logs are being generated on the local laptop even by using the batch file. But the issue is the logs are not being generated on the server....!!!!